# Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings on grails run-app

Tags: grails, logback

I'm getting following errors on `grails run-app`

```
Oct 20, 2014 6:22:22 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
| Configuring classpath
| Error SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/minhaj/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-    classic/1.0.12/logback-classic-1.0.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/minhaj/.m2/repository/org/grails/grails-plugin-    log4j/2.4.2/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
| Error SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

However I'm excluding `grails-plugin-log4j` explicitly but looks like its not working.

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes 'grails-plugin-log4j', 'log4j'
}
```

Does anyone face similar issue after adding logback plugin in grails application? (I'm using grails 2.4.2)

Comment: Is logging not working, or are you just concerned about the error Messages? That error should only be a concern if all of the bindings were expected to be active, but really only the plugin's will be, so usually it "just works". If you're not seeing log messages I'll dig in and fix the plugin.

Comment: We just dropped the idea to adding slf4j in project, may be i'll add it later when clear documentation available to add slf4j in grails project. Thanks @BurtBeckwith for the comment.